# What is a symmetric generating set of a group?

Tags: group-theory, graph-theory, cayley-graphs

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cayley_graph#Elementary_properties) states the following about Cayley graphs:

> The Cayley graph Γ(G,S) depends in an essential way on the choice of the set S of generators. For example, if the generating set S has k elements then each vertex of the Cayley graph has k incoming and k outgoing directed edges. In the case of a symmetric generating set S with r elements, the Cayley graph is a regular directed graph of degree r.

I understand the first case, where a generating set S of k elements creates a 2k-regular graph. But:

- What is a *symmetric generating set* S of r elements?
- How can it create a r-regular graph?

Comment: Closed under inversion.

Comment: so where the first case might be a set like {a,b}, the second case would be a set like {a,a^-1,b,b^-1}?

Comment: I agree that sentence is unclear. The last "directed" should probably be "undirected". I'll edit.